# Can dual booting (Windows 10 + Ubuntu 20.04) cause Driver/Hardware issues in Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10

So I have an Asus TUF A15(Ryzen 4800H/16GB RAM/1TB NVmeSSD / GTX 1660Ti 6GB) laptop which I purchased a year back only.

For some of my project work I need Linux, so I usually keep my machine in dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04 on one partition and Windows 10 on another partition.

But after a few months(10 months), I noticed that problem from Audio jack, that when I am in Windows 10, sometimes there was no audio output from the audio Jack. Whether I plug speakers or an external headset, there was simply no audio output.

I gave my device to Asus for repair(within warranty), and they said that the problem was due to my using my machine in dual boot mode and that probably the Other OS(Ubuntu) has caused issues to propagate into Windows 10.I was completely shocked to listen to such a statement.

And the thing is this problem has repeated for the second time and this time also they said the problem is with dual boot, and they reset my system and give it back to me. Though however the system after reset (which comes back to as same as a factory reset), works just fine for days, and then the problem again pops up. But thing is, I love gaming so I prefer Windows 10 but for my work-related tasks, I prefer Linux.

Can anyone advise that does really dual-booting Windows with Linux on separate partitions cause such issues?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Using Ubuntu will not affect your Windows installation unless you are somehow manipulating files or partitions that are associated with your Windows installation.

Actually, the opposite is sometimes true when you have the "fast boot" feature enabled in Windows 10. That's because fast boot is actually a hybrid suspend that does not fully shut down the system.  This can prevent you from accessing resources when you boot Ubuntu after Windows 10.

You might consider learning how to (re)install both operating systems because this is a fairly easy task that you do not need to take it somewhere to have it done.

Answer (score 1):

*Theoretical pondering* on Dual boot:
Sleep-mode is likely to save status of hardware and drivers in some way, which may well be inconsistent with what is expected (e.g. from hardware and/or file system status) at the time of boot (or revival from sleep mode?) in the other OS.

Suggestion: Avoid all types of "sleep mode" and fast boot - see if that keeps things working.

*If not anything else then you have refreshed (restarted, reset) your OS runtime data at every new reboot.*